# Mining on the testnet: how to configure bitcoin-qt?

Tags: bitcoin-core, testnet, miner-configuration

I am trying to generate some coins with 
the client ./bitcoin-qt -testnet -gen
How can I config to what address the money go ?

p.s.: actually I got notification for mining success but no coins in the wallet.

Comment: It takes 50 blocks for the wallet to have the coins.  you should see the pending transaction

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you found a block, but it got orphaned. Another miner may have found a block around the same time, and for whatever reason, the next miner to find a block chose to link to theirs instead of yours.

This happens a lot on testnet because of a special rule that if no block is found for 20 minutes, the difficulty drops temporarily to 1. When this happens, typically lots of people find blocks right away, and it's a toss up which one is used by the next miner.

You could inspect debug.log if you want to know exactly what happened.

Comment: Sounds reasonable

Answer (score 1):

The address is created in the wallet that is controlled by bitcoin-qt, so it will eventually pop up in your transactions, but the coins take time to mature. This is a security precaution to avoid transactions that spend coins from a block that will later be replaced. Using the [Bitcoin JSON-RPC](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list) might show them already even if they have not matured yet:

```
./bitcoin-qt -testnet listunspent 0
```

should list all unspent transaction outputs with at least 0 confirmations, i.e., everything. One of them should be your reward. From the output you can deduce the generating transaction's Hash and from there you can simply use `./bitcoin-qt -testnet gettransaction <txid>` to get details about the transaction.

Comment: ./bitcoin-qt -testnet listunspent 0 - tried that one, on windows it just run the application no list printed...

Comment: It's actually `bitcoind -testnet listunspent 0`, once you have the `bitcoind -testnet -daemon` running.